# Converting JSON file data values to SQL tables rows and columns

Tags: sql, json

I have the below code in JSON file :

```
{
    "took": 196,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 15,
        "successful": 15,
        "failed": 0
                },
    "hits": {
        "total": 165,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "logstash-2018.11.22",
                "_type": "nagios_core",
                "_id": "AWc6C_EtHRYvW4hmI7sl",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                 "message": "EXTERNAL COMMAND:  ACKNOWLEDGE_SVC_PROBLEM;DE-Hoeheinoed-VOC1-SRV;ntp_timesync;2;0;0;Jaizel Jem Perdon;SN 307185410",
                    "@version": "1",
                    "@timestamp": "2018-11-22T06: 12: 00.307Z",
                    "host": "172.26.66.59",
                    "port": 44154,
                    "type": "nagios_core",
                    "epoch_timestamp": "1542867118",
                    "nagios_severity_label": "EXTERNAL COMMAND",
                    "nagios_external_command": "ACKNOWLEDGE_SVC_PROBLEM",
                    "nagios_host": "DE-Hoeheinoed-VOC1-SRV",
                    "nagios_service": "ntp_timesync",
                    "nagios_sticky": "2",
                    "nagios_notify": "0",
                    "nagios_persistent": "0",
                    "nagios_author": "Jaizel Jem Perdon",
                    "nagios_comment": "SN 307185410",
                    "utc_timestamp": "2018-11-22T06: 11: 58.000Z"
                },
                "sort": [
                    1542867120307
                ]
            }  

        ]
    }
}
```

And i have the below code in SQL: However, I am getting null values in my result. As am new to JSON, am not able to find out the path of the JSON data values

```
Drop table if exists  #Temp1
Declare @JSON nvarchar(max)
SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '\\DKRDSDFSROOT10\Data\_Temp\MEIPE\ITE1452552_02test.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j


select @json as details


If (ISJSON(@json) = 1)
BEGIN 
  PRINT 'JOSN File is valid';

  select * into #Temp1
    from OPENJSON(@JSON, '$.hits')
 WITH 
     ( 
  [nagios_author] nvarchar(100) '$.hits.hits._source.nagios_author',
  [nagios_comment] nvarchar(100)   '$.hits.hits._source.nagios_comment'  
  )

  END 
  ELse

  Begin 
  PRINT 'JOSN File is invalid';

  END 


  select * from #Temp1
```

Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using below code and it worked

`WITH 
     ( 
  [nagios_author] nvarchar(100) '$.hits[0]._source.nagios_author',
  [nagios_comment] nvarchar(100)   '$.hits[0]._source.nagios_comment'

  )`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the second hits array in your json as an object, but its an array try to change your query as follows:

```
 select * into #Temp1
    from OPENJSON(@JSON, '$.hits')
 WITH 
     ( 
  [nagios_author] nvarchar(100) '$.hits.hits[0]._source.nagios_author',
  [nagios_comment] nvarchar(100)   '$.hits.hits[0]._source.nagios_comment'  
  )
```